# Grep for specific numbers within a text file and output per number text file

Tags: linux, grep, bioinformatics

I have a text file `chunk_names.txt` that looks like this:

```
chr1_12334_64321
chr1_134435_77474   
chr10_463252_74754
chr10_54265_423435 
chr13_5464565_547644567
```

This is an example but all chromosomes are represented (1...22, X and Y). All entries follow the same format`chr{1..22, X or Y}_*string of numbers*__*string of numbers*`.

I would like to split these into per chromosome files e.g. all of the chunks starting chr10 to be put into a file called `chr10.txt`:

In Linux I have tried :

```
for i in {1..22}
do 
    grep chr$i chunk_names.txt > chr$i.txt 
done
```

However, the `chr1.txt` output file now contains all the chromosome chunks with 1 in them (1,10,11,12, etc).

How would I modify this script to separate out the chromosomes?

I also haven't tackled how to include chromosome X or Y within the same script and am currently running that separately

Things I have tried :

```
grep -o gives me just "chr$i" as an output 
grep 'chr$i' gives me blank files
grep "chr$i" has the initial problem
```

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the `_` following the number you can distinguish between `chr1_` and e.g.   `chr10_`. To include `X` and `Y`, simply include these in the loop

```
for i in {1..22} X Y
do 
    grep "chr${i}_" chunk_names.txt > chr$i.txt 
done
```

To search at the beginning of the line only you can add a leading `^` to the pattern

```
    grep "^chr${i}_" chunk_names.txt > chr$i.txt
```

**Explanation about your attempts:**

`grep chr$i` searches for the pattern anywhere in the line. The shell replaces `$i` with the value of the variable `i`, so you get `chr1`, `chr2` etc.

If you enclose the pattern in double quotes as `grep "chr$i"` the shell will not do any file name globbing or splitting of the string, but still expand variables. In your case it is the same as without quotes.

If you use single quotes, the shell takes the literal string as is, so you always search for a line that contains `chr$i` (instead of `chr1` etc.) which does not occur in your file.

**Explanation about quotes:**

The quotes in my proposed solution are not necessary in your case, but it is a good habit to quote everything. If your pattern would contain spaces or characters that are special to the shell, the quoting will make a difference.

Example:

If your file would contain a `chr1*` instead of the `chr1_`, the pattern `chr${i}*` would be replaced by the list of matching files.

When you already created your output files `chr1.txt` etc., try these commands

```
$ i=1; echo chr$i*
chr10.txt chr11.txt chr12.txt chr13.txt chr14.txt chr15.txt chr16.txt chr17.txt chr18.txt chr19.txt chr1.txt
$ i=1; echo "chr$i*"
chr1*
```

In the first case, the `grep`command

```
    grep chr${i}* chunk_names.txt
```

would be expanded as

```
    grep chr10.txt chr11.txt chr12.txt chr13.txt chr14.txt chr15.txt chr16.txt chr17.txt chr18.txt chr19.txt chr1.txt chunk_names.txt
```

which would search for the pattern `chr10.txt` in files `chr11.txt` ... `chr1.txt` and `chunk_names.txt`.

Comment: Many thanks Bodo! Out of interest when I try grep chr${i}_ chunk_names.txt > chr$i.txt  I get the same result (the correct one) what purpose do the quotation marks serve?

Comment: I will add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for taking the time to explain this, coming from a non-computational background it's super helpful to have someone explain things step by step.

Answer (score 3):

Your 'for' loop will mean parsing your file N times (where N is the number of chromosomes/contigs in your list). Here's an agnostic approach using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) that will parse the file just once:

```
awk -F '_' '{ print > $1 ".txt" }' chunk_names.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! To go through what this means: -F is delimiter so does '_' mean space? Print $1 is print column 1 and end it with .txt?

Comment: `-F '_'` specifies the input field separator, so the input line will be split into fields at `_`. Then `$1` will be the first field, i.e. everything before the first '_'. (Or the whole line if it doesn't contain a `_`.) `print` without arguments prints the whole line and `> $1 ".txt"` redirects the output to a file which is named as the first field (`$1`) with `.txt` appended, i.e. `chr1.txt` etc.